# boostrap4: How to match cards by height AND ensure correct breakpoints?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a button group inside the footer of my cards that takes up some space. Before, I put each individual card in a `div` like this:

```
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-3"></div>
```

However, now I want to make sure the cards are the same height. I tried doing this using card decks. I was able to get the height right, but now the cards stay next to each other for too long, and the button group goes outside of the card. This is what it looks like:

[image]

I tried adding the col-12 stuff into the card tag like this:

```
  <div class="card col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-3 card-col"></div>
```

This did not do anything unfortunately. How can I achieve both goals: same height and sufficient width for button group?

Particularly, I want to be able to use the height feature of card-deck in combination with the grid system of Bootstrap so that columns start like this:

```
||||
```

Then become this:

```
||
||
```

Then finally become this:

```
|
|
|
|
```

**EDIT** - complete code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row card-deck">
  <div class="card my-3">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Date</h6>
      <p class="card-text">Description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary viewActivity">View</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success editActivity">Edit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger deleteActivity">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***Solution***

```html
   

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <style>
    .card{
    height:100%;
    }
    </style>

      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-3 card-col mb-3">
      <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
     <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"></h6>
        <p class="card-text"></p>
      </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
     <div class="btn-group" role="group">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary viewActivity">View</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-success editActivity">Edit</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger deleteActivity">Delete</button>
     </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Provide actual code instead of images. Should we be writing the code we see in the image and go on wasting time or just use the code you give us? :)

Comment: @weegee I provided more detail. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having is due to the default padding on `.card-footer` & `.btn`, you can override these paddings to get a clean look where you're struggling i.e. between 576px & 700px;

**working snippet** below:

```css
.card-footer {
  text-align: center !important;
  padding: .75rem 0 !important;
}

@media screen and (min-width:576px) and (max-width:700px) {
  .btn {
    padding: .375rem 0.3rem !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row card-deck">
  <div class="card col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 card-col">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Long Title that (we have)</h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Date</h6>
      <p class="card-text">Description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary viewActivity">View</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success editActivity">Edit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger deleteActivity">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 card-col">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Date</h6>
      <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla laborum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary viewActivity">View</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success editActivity">Edit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger deleteActivity">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 card-col">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Medium Title</h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Date</h6>
      <p class="card-text">Description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary viewActivity">View</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success editActivity">Edit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger deleteActivity">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Place the style tag after the bootstrap.css in your page to avoid putting `!important` (which i had to put here to recreate the fix)

**update**: in light of questioner's comment below

```css
.card-footer {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container-fluid ">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="card col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-3 card-col">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Long Title that (we have)</h5>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Date</h6>
        <p class="card-text">Description</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary viewActivity">View</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success editActivity">Edit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger deleteActivity">Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-3 card-col">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Date</h6>
        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla laborum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary viewActivity">View</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success editActivity">Edit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger deleteActivity">Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-3 card-col">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Medium Title</h5>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Date</h6>
        <p class="card-text">Description</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary viewActivity">View</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success editActivity">Edit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger deleteActivity">Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-3 card-col">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Medium Title</h5>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Date</h6>
        <p class="card-text">Description</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary viewActivity">View</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success editActivity">Edit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger deleteActivity">Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This makes sense. Now the problem is that the cards look very thin and long during small screen-sizes instead of collapsing. Please check my edit. I guess I am trying to fnd a way to use card-deck and the grid system to ensure proper column behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I like that solution. Now, I am trying to separate the cards a little bit, but adding horizontal margin messes up the column structure (since the margin is added to the columns and the card). I tried adding `m-2` to the `.card-col` div.

Comment: Never mind, figured it out. Please check my new edit.